# codeigniter - php - dosen't insert to the database

Tags: php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I try to insert some information from my registration page.
I make all the function with the 'MVC' model.
the code :

**Register Page:**

```
<main>
    <div id="mainWrraper">

        <p id="error"></p>

        <?php echo form_open('login_controller/insertData'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Registration:</legend>
            <div class="inputWrapper"><label>First name: </label><input id="First_name" class="formInput" type="text" name="First_name"></div>
            <div class="inputWrapper"><label>Last name: </label><input id="Last_name" class="formInput" type="text" name="Last_name"></div>
            <div class="inputWrapper"><label>Email: </label><input id="Email" class="formInput" type="text" name="Email"></div>
            <div class="inputWrapper"><label>Username: </label><input id="Username" class="formInput" type="text" name="Username"></div>
            <div class="inputWrapper"><label>Password: </label><input id="Password" class="formInput" type="password" name="Password"></div>
                        <div class="inputWrapper"><label>Confirm Password: </label><input id="Confirm_password" class="formInput" type="password" name="Confirm_password"></div>
                        <div class="inputWrapper"><label>Year Of Birth: </label><input id="Year_Of_Birth" class="formInput" type="text" name="Year_Of_Birth"></div>
                        <!--<div class="inputWrapper"><label>Date Of Birth: </label><input id="Date_B" class="formInput" type="date" name="Date_B"></div>-->
            <div class="inputWrapper"><label> Location:</label><select id="Location" name="Location">
                    <option value="Central">Central</option>
                    <option value="South">South</option>
                    <option value="North">North</option>
                </select></div>
                        <div class="inputWrapper"><label> Gender:</label><select id="Gender" name="Gender">
                    <option value="Women">Women</option>
                    <option value="Men">Men</option>
                </select></div>
            <div class="inputWrapper"><input id="register" type="button" value="register" name="submit">
        </fieldset>

        </form>

    </div>
</main>

<script>
    $("#register").click(function() {
        var First_name = $("#First_name").val();
        var Last_name = $("#Last_name").val();
        var Email = $("#Email").val();
        var Username = $("#Username").val();
        var Password = $("#Password").val();
                var Confirm_password = $("#Confirm_password").val();
        var Year_Of_Birth = $("#Year_Of_Birth").val();
        var Location = $("#Location").val();
        var Gender = $("#Gender").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>"+"/login_controller/insertData",
            data: {
                First_name: First_name,
                Last_name: Last_name,
                Email: Email,
                Username: Username,
                Password: Password,
                                Confirm_password: Confirm_password,
                Year_Of_Birth: Year_Of_Birth,
                                Location: Location,
                Gender: Gender
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('Something is wrong');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                if (data === "1") {
                    alert("Registration succedded");
                    window.location.href = "<?php echo site_url('login_controller/login');?>";
                } else {
                    $("#error").html(data);
                }
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

**Login_Controller:**

```
<?php

class login_controller  extends CI_Controller {
     public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('login_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
                $this->load->helper('form');
                $this->load->library('session');
        }

        public function login()
        {        
                $data['user']=NULL;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('login_page/login', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }
         public function logout()
        {
             $data = array('User_name','Password');
             $this->session->unset_userdata($data);
             redirect("login_controller/login");                        
        }


        public function auth(){
            $data = array(
               'Username' => $this->input->post('Username'),
               'Password' => md5($this->input->post('Password'))

             );

            $check=$this->login_model->auth($data);

           if ($check==false){
                $data['error']= array("message"=>"User is not found");
                $data['user'] = NULL;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('login_page/login', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');
            }
            else{
               $data['user'] = $check;
               $this->session->set_userdata($data);
               redirect("web_controller/home");
            }
        }
         public function register()
        {
                $data['user']=NULL;
                $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
                $this->load->view('login_page/register', $data);
                $this->load->view('templates/footer');

        }

           public function check($data){

            $error ='';

            if($data['First_name'] == NULL)
            {
                 $error .= "Enter your first name properly"."<br>";
            }
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$data['First_name'])) 
            {
                $error .= "Enter only letters in the first name"."<br>";
            }
            if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$data['Last_name'])) 
            {
                $error .= "Enter only letters in the last name"."<br>";
            }
            if($data['Last_name'] == NULL)
            {
                $error .= "Enter your last name properly"."<br>";
            }    
           if(!filter_var($data['Email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
           {
               $error .= "Invalid email format"."<br>";
           }
            if($data['Password'] != $data['Confirm_password'])
            {
                $error .= " The passwords didn't match"."<br>";
            }

           return $error;
        }

        public function insertData(){
           $data = array(
                'First_name' => $this->input->post('First_name'),
                'Last_name' => $this->input->post('Last_name'),
                'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
                'Username' => str($this->input->post('Username')),
                'Password' => md5($this->input->post('Password')),
                'Confirm_password' => md5($this->input->post('Confirm_password')),
                'Year_Of_Birth' => $this->input->post('Year_Of_Birth'),
                'Location' => $this->input->post('Location'),
                'Gender' => $this->input->post('Gender')                
            );

           $error = $this->check($data);
           if($error == '')
           {
               $error_db = $this->login_model->insertData($data);
               if($error_db==NULL){
                   $data['info']=array("message"=>"1");
               }
               else{
                    $data['info']=array("message"=> "Error. Registration faild: ".$error_db["message"] );
               }
               echo $data["info"]["message"];
               print_r($data);
           }
           else{
               echo $error; 
               echo $data['First_name'];
           }    

        } 
}
```

**Login_Model :**

```
<?php

class login_model extends CI_Model {

     public function __construct()
     {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->database();
     }
     public function auth($data)
      {
            $query = $this->db->query("select * from users where Username = '".$data['Username']."' and Password ='".$data['Password']."'");
            if($query){   
                return $query->result_array();
        }
        return false;           
      }

        public function insertData($data){
             $this->db->db_debug = FALSE; 

             $error=NULL;
              if (!$this->db->insert('users', $data)){
                  $error=$this->db->error();
              }
              echo "Test Message";
              return $error;
        }
}
```

The Problem is when i click on 'Register' at 'Register page'.
when i click it, i jump into line 62 (at the register page code) `alert('Something is wrong');`
and in the DevTools is show me :[image: Error From DevTools]

My database look like this : [image: Database Photo]

and in the web its look like this (the alert show here) : [image: Website look]

Hope i explain myself good, i just want to insert my data to the database.
thanks alot !

**EDIT #1:**
I thinks the problem is the connetcion from the controller to model.
it's looklike he dosen't recognize the model function (and file).

Comment: We cannot help you without the code that do the insertion

Comment: @JoffreySchmitz i have update the view of the post .
you can look now better .

Answer (score 0):

**Cause**

You are trying to insert the data without fields **Location** and **Gender** as you have commented them in line no 101 and 102. All the fields in the given table are mandatory to insert. Thus, you are getting 500 Internal error.

**How to fix it -**

Either you uncomment those two lines (101 and 102) or set a default value to both fields in the table.

Comment: Hey!
I bring they back, and still, got the same error.

Comment: i update the code and the view of the code in my post. @mail2bapi

Comment: ```print_r($data); ``` inside th method insertData($data) in your model. Please share the output.

Comment: Then print it just after its declaration in insertData() method in your controller.